# Facebook SDK Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, xcode4.3

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've been snooping around here looking for an answer, but have yet to find one.  I've tried what other people have suggested, as in using an older SDK copy but still get this linker error. The SDK tutorial [Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) suggests after running the script they include to drag the folder into your project.  When I drag the folder I get problems.  When I create a directory in my project for the files and just drag the files, then it works, but still with this linker error.

Am I missing something else?  I've followed the tutorial to the " T " and still can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: What about simply copying some files manually to your project and not messing with various/bogus architectured static libraries?

Comment: Are you suggesting just coping the src file over?  The documentation mentions if you are using ARC not to do that, but to run the script for the static libraries.

Comment: The static libraries suck... Instead, if you use ARC, comment out the releases from the code, or whatever. Messing with the static libraries is risky, as there are a *lot* of properties in Xcode/LLVM which have to be properly set in order the linker to find the Facebook code (which it fails to do at the time).

Comment: I went through the SRC files and commented out the releases, then put it into my project,  but still get the Linker error. Is this what your were saying to do?

Comment: Yes it was, and now you're really not supposed to get the linker error. Are you sure Xcode compiles the source files along with your project's files? (that's why I hate using IDEs... If you were compiling it manually or by a Makefile, this would never happen...)

Comment: I had a .a that wasn't added as a linked library.  Once it was added, works now!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: which was the .a file u had not linked? i am also getting same error..

Comment: I believe it was `libfacebook_ios_sdk.a`.  I had to link it in the Build Phases.